# changing 2d list with for loops in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to do Conway's game of life in python, but i'm getting weird output. The print statements are for debug purposes.

```
def dead_state(width, height):
     #build a board that is size width x height
     board = []
     for col in range(width):
         board.append(0)
     state = [board]

     for row in range(height - 1):
         state.append(board)

     return state


def random_state(width, height):
    #build board with dead_state
    board = dead_state(width, height)

    #randomize board
    print("before randomizing: " + str(board)) 

    for row in range(height):

        for col in range(width):
            print("board[" + str(row) + "] before: " + str(board[row][col]))
            if random.random() > 0.5:
                board[row][col] = 1
            else:
                board[row][col] = 0
         print("board[" + str(row) + "][" + str(col) + "] after: " + str(board[row][col]))



    print("board after randomizing: " + str(board))

    return board
```

when this runs, it randomizes the indices within a row, but then makes every row the same.

one output:

```
board after randomizing: 
[
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
]
```

Comment: show your dead_state function that builds the 2d list. likely you have created your lists with * like `[]*4` this will create 4 references all to the same list, so changing one will change the others as they all point to the same list

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]. What is `dead_state` function doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its likely that the issue lies in your dead_states code which creates your board. Chances are your creating your list of lists using multiply to create n number of lists.This will create one list and then make n references to it in you outer list. We can see this with a simple example. we create of inner lists which each have 3 empty strings. we then update the value of the 2nd item in the first list setting it to 1, but as you see it updates the value of all lists. this is because they way we created the nested lists.

```py
my_lists = [['', '', '']] * 4
print(my_lists)
my_lists[0][1] = 1
print(my_lists)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
[['', 1, ''], ['', 1, ''], ['', 1, ''], ['', 1, '']]
```

Instead we should create the nested lists using list comprehension and range. This will create 4 separate lists in memory and each list is unique and changing element 2 in list 1 changes only that list.

```py
my_lists = [['', '', ''] for _ in range(4)]
print(my_lists)
my_lists[0][1] = 1
print(my_lists)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
[['', 1, ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it! I used the list comp. Before I was just appending 0 to a list and then appending that list to the list of lists. This is much easier to understand.